# Avatar change not persisting across Network sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, gravatar

I changed my Gravatar the other day but I had forgotten the e-mail I was changing it on was linked to StackOverflow. So this resulted in my SO Gravatar being changed (to a picture of my foot with a frowny face, circa 2003).

I didn't want this image associated with my SE accounts and instead of changing my e-mail, I decided to take the lazy option and upload an image to use as my Avatar with the new(ish) feature.

I am pretty sure I changed the avatar via my [SO Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193596/amicable) and the change seems to have been applied to my [SE Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1228525/amicable) also.

However if you take a look at my [SO.Meta Profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/188759/amicable) or [Workplace Profile](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/5550/amicable) you can see they are displaying the Gravatar associated with my e-mail instead.

Comment: Did you save the changes just to SO or for the whole network?

Comment: That is, [what did you click on](http://i.imgur.com/M5OWm2m.png)?

Comment: Bart: Ah, that could easily be it, seeing as SO seems to be the only one with it, I don't remember if I clicked that button.
If that's the case though, why is my SO Avatar the one displayed on my Network profile.

Comment: There is a reason for that and each time someone asks it I blank on what it was... @Oded surely has the answer... ( /me runs ).

Comment: OK. I don't believe I was actually presented with that option. I just changed my Meta avatar image and it did not appear.

Comment: It does appear when I click edit profile. But not when I click the mouseover link from my avatar.

Comment: Ha, I hadn't noticed that option. Perhaps that does not automatically copy to all the other profiles. No idea if the other route will do that for your avatar.

Comment: The avatar from the exchange site where you have most reputation is the one used, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Bart - It doesn't copy automatically. Some people want to have different avatars for each site.

Comment: @Oded Okay, so the solution is, go the edit profile route and click on the copy button?

Comment: @Bart - Yes - that should copy the info, including avatar URL to all other linked accounts.

Comment: @Bart: Yes. That's what I had to do. If you just use [this button](http://imgur.com/1RUTSr5) you aren't presented with the option to copy to all SE sites.